# Adding international character into font?

Tags: css, fonts

How can I add an international character into font? I am designing a website with awesome font but it doesn't support Č, Ć, Š etc...

Can I create and add it?

Font is BebasNeue.

thanks

Comment: Yes, but you'd have to edit the font file and that's not trivial. Google `font editor` to get started (or look for a similar font, might be the easier way)

Comment: I have never done anything like that...thanks. Can I copy character from other font? :)

Comment: In theory yes, but it's not easy to do and most likely wouldn't look good. You'll probably be better off looking for a similar-looking font

Comment: thanks a lot, I'd probably waste few hours and end up searching for a new one

Answer (score 2):

assuming the font is this one http://www.dafont.com/bebas-neue.font it does not seem to include the characters you need, so the only way (save implementing it on your own) would be to choose a different font.

Comment: yes, thats the font! I'll try search for a similar one...but this one is great imho and it suits my needs perfectly.

Comment: You will have to design the glyphs yourself, and then add them into the font file. This is not exactly the easiest thing to do (because designing glyphs are for designers), and you might run into issues for modifying the font file (please check the licenses). Like what Hexblot as recommended, you're better off choosing another font.

Comment: it's really not worth the time and effort put into it, especially since you can find others that are similar. For instance, you can try Oswald http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Oswald